# Run a JavaScript script when excel file trigger an action

Tags: javascript, excel, automation, triggers, puppeteer

I'm using **puppeteer** to automate some processes, one of them that i want to open an excel file reading the data inside and search the web using this data (open google-->search using the cell's data).

- I can do this correctly using Java script, **but** **i want to know if i can run puppeteer when an excel trigger occurs?**

  because i don't want this to happen randomly i want it to happen when a specific event occurs inside excel sheet.
- I've been searching for a while and i couldn't find useful resource. I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=excel-js-preview#onchanged
  but it didn't help me alot as i couldn't understand how to use it.

**example:**

> I have an excel file containing only 1 cell {facbook}. So i was
> wondering if there is a way that allows me to run a [java script
> script through cmd - that controls puppeteer] when i set another cell on excel to
> be = {open}. So whenever a cell CHANGES it's value in excel sheet this
> triggers the script i have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exceljs from node js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var Excel = require('exceljs');

//reading test.xlsx
wb.xlsx.readFile('test.xlsx').then(function(){
  sh = wb.getWorksheet("sheet1");    
    start_page(sh);
});
//running new browser 
async function start_page(sh){  
    var i = 2;

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});

    while(i <= sh.rowCount){
        var result_cell = sh.getRow(i).getCell(3).text;
        await open_page(browser, result_cell);
        i ++;
    }
}

async function open_page(browser, result_cell) {

    const page = await browser.newPage();   
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(10000);        

    await page.goto('testurl', {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
    });

    your code here

    page.close();
}
```

Those are the sample code I have done for another project. You can check it with those code.

Comment: would you explain it a little bit ?